# Assign background color based on value of the cell

Tags: jquery, razor

```
  var $tr = $('<tr>').append(
                    $('<td>').text(item.trade_details["trade_type"]),
                    $('<td>').text(item.trade_details["quantity"]),
                    $('<td>').text(item.trade_details["security_id"]),
                    $('<td>').text(item.trade_details["price"]),
                    $('<td>').text(item.trade_details["portfolio_name"]),
                    $('<td>').text(item.trade_details["block_id"])
                );
                $("#" + table_name + " tbody").append($tr);
```

Above is the code where I am assigning values to table .
For couple of rows, block_id will be the same. Based on block_id, how can we change background color ?

Comment: Use css class, eg `$("<tr>").append(...).addClass("bg_" + item.trade_details["block_id"]);`   without knowing how block_id relates to the colour you want, can't really add more than that.

Comment: For example: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/crt8xydo/